# how to redirect in jsp using <jsp:forward> with a relative url

Tags: java, jsp, jsp-tags

I'm trying to redirect from a page to another
always use
 `<jsp:forward page='/some_page.jsp' />`or
 `response.sendRedirect(/some_page.jsp)`

but in this case I need to redirect to another page
someting like home/try/page and I try to use
`<jsp:forward page='home/try/page' />` but it doesn't work some help?

Comment: are you sure that the JSP which which has this code is in the same directory as home?  if home is in document root you might try <jsp:forward page='/home/try/page' />

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<jsp:forward /> tag is intended for forwarding the request on to a relative url.
```

now you want to redirect your page here - 'home/try/page'. If your want to redirect from one directory to another directory page than try something like below -

```
 <jsp:forward page="/home/try/page.jsp"/>
 <jsp:forward page="../home/try/page.jsp"/>
 or
 <jsp:forward page="../../home/try/page.jsp"/>
```

"../" will get you out from the current folder.

For example -  let assume we requested the following URL, -

```
http://localhost/myJSPApp/Security/login.jsp
```

When the file "login.jsp" executes it performs the following  action

```
<jsp:forward page="../Welcome/Welcome.jsp" />
```

This is a forward to another JSP in another folder "Welcome" which is at the same level as the "Security" folder.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: thanks, I only makig a bad redirect but with a JSTL tag everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to move up the "tree" to get to a different folder. For example, if you are current in page x.jsp in folder "foo" and need to get to page y.jsp in folder "bar", you would need to do this
   - jsp: forward page='../bar/y.jsp'.

The "../" tells jsp to back out of the current folder(foo) it is in and look for the next folder(bar). You would need to add one "../" for each level you go up.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have the next <js:forward page='/c/page'/> /c is obtained with themeDisplay.getPathMain() method from liferay